# How to generate a column that shows how many invoices have been cleared prior to the current invoice?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have three columns, the `CLEAR_DATE` column, which states on which date the invoice has been cleared (i.e. has been paid). If there is a NA clearing date, it means that the invoice has not been paid yet. The `INVOICE_DATE` column, which shows the date on which the current invoice has been generated and finally an `ACCOUNT` column specifies which customer account this is.

I would like to count which invoices have been cleared prior to the current invoice date per account. My code is straight forward, but I have not been able to produce a vectorised approach on this yet. I was wondering what I am missing or whether it is possible to vectorise this.

```
def count_cleared(r):
    return df.loc[(df[df['CLEAR_DATE'].notna()] < row['INVOICE_DATE'])].shape(0)
    
df['prior_cleared_invoices'] = df.groupby(['ACCOUNT']).apply(lambda x: x.apply(count_cleared, axis=1))
```

Some example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ACCOUNT': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'INVOICE_DATE': pd.to_datetime(['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-01-01']),
    'CLEAR_DATE': pd.to_datetime(['2022-01-15', '2022-02-28', np.nan, '2022-01-31', '2022-03-01', '2022-02-01'])
})
```

Here is the expected output:

```
  ACCOUNT INVOICE_DATE CLEAR_DATE  prior_cleared_invoices
0       A   2022-01-01 2022-01-15                     0.0
1       A   2022-02-01 2022-02-28                     1.0
2       A   2022-03-01        NaT                     2.0
3       B   2022-01-01 2022-01-31                     0.0
4       B   2022-03-01 2022-03-01                     1.0
5       C   2022-01-01 2022-02-01                     0.0
```

Comment: Can you provide some data as plain text, please?

Comment: Now you have updated your code with sample, what should be the expected output?

Comment: Why for (A, 2022-03-01) count is 1 and not 2? At this date 2 invoices are paid, right?

Comment: My apologies, you are entirely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use np.searchsorted:

```
def count_cleared(df):
    count = np.searchsorted(df['CLEAR_DATE'].sort_values(),
                            df['INVOICE_DATE'])
    return pd.Series(count, df.index).to_frame()

df['prior_cleared_invoices'] = (df.groupby('ACCOUNT', group_keys=False)
                                  .apply(count_cleared))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  ACCOUNT INVOICE_DATE CLEAR_DATE  prior_cleared_invoices
0       A   2022-01-01 2022-01-15                       0
1       A   2022-02-01 2022-02-28                       1
2       A   2022-03-01        NaT                       2
3       B   2022-01-01 2022-01-31                       0
4       B   2022-03-01 2022-03-01                       1
5       C   2022-01-01 2022-02-01                       0
```